# How to design a gridview or table with datasource having blank first row in which we can search table column in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I want to design a grid view or table that gets data from database then i want leave first row blank. when user click in the cells of first row and type in, it shows every data that matches.

Answer (score 0):

You can use textBoxes to query your requested data in gridView and use onTextBoxChanged to update the gridView. Instead of increasing the code you also can do it using Table let's say you have 5 columns on the gridView you make table with 5 columns and 2 rows, the first row you put 1 textBox in each cell, in the second column you use colspan property and set it to 5. Then use the event onTextBoxChanged call the SQL command and query the data on textBox then update the gridView.

Comment: Thank you for your answering. I want to do that in client-side and when i use textbox, it doesnt look good between cells.in addition, i get data from database and row[0] of table in database placed in row[0] of gridview. I look for appearance like excel cells. i saw an example in a software but i dont know how they design that